# HABTM relationship with rails API does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am new in Ruby on Rails. I am making a Rails API using Rails 5.1, active record serializer, doorkeeper and devise gem.

I have an `Order` table and it has many products. The relation between order and product is many-to-many.

Order model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord      
  validates_presence_of :brute, :net
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products      
end
```

Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  validates_presence_of :name, :price
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```

I have a join table named `orders_products`.

Order serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :discount, :brute, :net, :payed, :payed_at, :products      

  def products
    object.products.map do |product|
      ProductSerializer.new(product, scope: scope, root: false, event: object)
    end
  end

end
```

Product serializer:

```
 class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :price, :description
  has_one :category
end
```

Order controller:

```
module Api
  class OrdersController < ApiController
    before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /api/orders
    def index
      @orders = Order.all

      render json: @orders
    end

    # GET /api/orders/1
    def show
      render json: @order
    end

    # POST /api/orders
    def create
      @order = Order.new(order_params)

      if @order.save
        render json: @order, status: :created, location: api_order_url(@order)
      else
        render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /api/orders/1
    def update
      if @order.present?
        if @order.update(order_params)
          render json: @order
        else
          render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /api/orders/1
    def destroy
      @order.destroy if @order.present?
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      Rails.logger.error{ 'Order record is not found' }
      nil
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:discount, :brute, :net, :payed, :payed_at, product_ids: [])
    end
  end
end
```

When I post some order json data from API generator app like Postman/Insomnia, Order is being saved in orders table but no data saved in `orders_products` join table.

My request(POST http://localhost:3000/api/orders) of order json:

```
{
        "discount": 110,
        "brute": 100,
        "net": 200,
        "payed": null,
        "payed_at": null,          
        "product_ids": [3]
}
```

I try to find the solution but I failed.

Comment: I don't use serializer so I am not that much familiar with some bits of your code. Though can you point where in your code you add the products to your order ? Maybe you can copy the view (erb) file where this is handled too..

Comment: I am also facing same problem . But there is none erb file while you're using active record serializer gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have solved in your problem.Just add an attribute in your model.

Order Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :product_ids
  validates_presence_of :brute, :net
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products      
end
```

Order Serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :discount, :brute, :net, :payed, :payed_at
  has_many :products
end
```

And create method in your order api:

```
# POST /api/orders
    def create
      @order = Order.new(order_params)

      if @order.save
        # Find products
        @products = Product.where(id: order_params[:product_ids])
        # Create join table records
        @products.each { |product| product.orders << @order }

        render json: @order, status: :created, location: api_order_url(@order)
      else
        render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
```

I have tested in locally and it works! Happy Programming :)

Comment: Thanks @Engr. Tanbir Hasan, You deserve a medal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Rails doesn't automatically handle creating the join records when given a list of ids. Therefore when you're calling `@order = Order.new(order_params)` and expecting it to know how to handle `product_ids: [3]`, it's just ignoring it.

If you modify your `create` endpoint with the below, you should see the join records being created.

```
# POST /api/orders
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  if @order.save
    # Find products
    @products = Product.where(id: order_params[:product_ids])
    # Create join table records
    @products.each { |product| product.orders << order }

    render json: @order, status: :created, location: api_order_url(@order)
  else
    render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

This is just one possible solution that doesn't do any error checking. Depending how secure and robust your application needs to be you may need to create a service that wraps this and handles validating that products are found before creating the order and associating the records.

EDIT: OrderSerializer

Once you've verified that the join table records are being created properly. Check that your serializers are working, they have great documentation. I believe you can swap out your current `products` method in the `OrderSerializer` with this:

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :discount, :brute, :net, :payed, :payed_at, :products      

  def products
    object.products.map do |product|
      ProductSerializer.new(product).serializable_hash
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: order_params[:product_ids] returns nil when I requested from json API. Why ?

Comment: It sounds like you have two problems. The first problem is that the join table records aren't being created. The solution I presented above should fix that, have you verified that records are now being created? If they are and your json output is still incorrect, then your Order serializer is wrong. Adding info above.

Comment: Your given method is correct, I checked it @products = Product.where(id: 3), then join table is being created. But when I debug and find that order_params[:product_ids] returns always nil and order_params does not contain any product_ids! Is my json format incorrect ?
Your `serializable_hash` returns error, it requires two missing arguments.

Comment: Updated code, removing the excess parameters you were passing into the `ProductSerializer`. I've tested this on a local repository and it works as expected. If you're still getting errors you're going to need to post more details and maybe even link the repo.

Comment: Post the full error you're receiving. No one can solve this for you without detailed information.